# How to cast the output of a for loop into a single list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup I have collected the data from a web page weather table. I managed to scrape the text from a specific column by looping trough all 14 rows and indexing by [0].

However by iterating trough the table rows it puts the text in descending order line by line, like:

```
Maandag 13 mei
Dinsdag 14 mei
Woensdag 15 mei
Donderdag 16 mei
Vrijdag 17 mei
Zaterdag 18 mei
Zondag 19 mei
Maandag 20 mei
Dinsdag 21 mei
Woensdag 22 mei
Donderdag 23 mei
Vrijdag 24 mei
Zaterdag 25 mei
Zondag 26 mei
Maandag 27 mei
```

`print(list(days)` doesn't work it just transforms every item into a separate list and still in descending order.

```
TableRows = table.find_all('tr')

CleanTableRows = TableRows[2:]

for tr in (CleanTableRows):
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows = [item.text for item in td]

    days = rows[0]

    print(days)
```

I want to cast it into a list of strings like:

```
['Maandag 13 mei', 'Dinsdag 14 mei', 'Woensdag 15 mei', 'Donderdag 16 mei', 'Vrijdag 17 mei', 'Zaterdag 18 mei', 'Zondag 19 mei', 'Maandag 20 mei', 'dinsdag 21 mei', 'Woensdag 22 mei', 'Donderdag 23 mei', 'Vrijdag 24 mei', 'Zaterdag 25 mei', 'Zondag 26 mei', 'Maandag 27 mei']
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Could you add the source, so the pandas dataframe itself maybe?

Comment: If days is a string, then you might want to use days.split("\n") to split days at every newline, leaving you with a list of every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
data = []
for tr in (CleanTableRows):
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows = [item.text for item in td]

    days = rows[0]
    data.append(days)
    print(days)

print(data) # This is a list which contains all your days data
```